# Matlab fopen fails to open file name passed as string variable but opens when passed as string

Tags: matlab, fopen

Hi all I'm trying to read in files using a variable and for some reason when I pass the same string as a variable it no longer opens. Below I try the same command simply swapping the variable for its contents and get different results? I also tried DEBLANK and STRTRIM from checking other questions.

```
f=fopen(fname,'r');

f

f =
    -1

fname 

fname =

/xchip/cga_home/amaro/Cranios/Segs/001-CN-001-CN-N.tsv

f=fopen('/xchip/cga_home/amaro/Cranios/Segs/001-CN-001-CN-N.tsv','r');

f

f=3
```

Comment: Do a `clear all` and then re-create variables and check again. The example isn't helping

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry the example wasn't helpful. I solved this problem by reverting to an older version of matlab from 2013a to 2012b. Basically matlab 2013a was treating the file handle differently when passed as a variable.